# About hosting Kaa on commercial web host company

Tags: web-services, kaa

I wonder if that is possible to host kaa server on a commercial web hosting company. For example, if I have a web hosted on godaddy called myxyz.io. Can I install kaa server on my host website and collect data from endpoints? I know this is possible to port to AWS, but how about any Linux based servers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I installed it on an Ubuntu 16.04 with public IP address. But make sure you do have the necessary ports for Kaa server open on your hosting site, or else communication is blocked.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. But what I want to know is if I have a website running by commercial web hosting company, such as godaddy or hostgator, is Kaa servers available for installation? Thanks.

Comment: I guess that should not be a problem,as long as the OS is linux and you are given root access to those services you mentioned, and all the ports required can be set as open on those services you mentioned, I am not a godaddy or hostgator user so I have no idea. But as long as a hosting site allows you to make those setup stuff then there should be no problem. Then in the Kaa server management profile just make sure you change the URL registered to whatever your web service gives you, and then after that, generate all SDKs for your devices(SDK are affected by URL recorded in Kaa server profile)